# LESS: Combine multiple CSS3 animation

Tags: less, css-animations

I have 2 CSS animations defined in LESS:

```
.color_animation (@color, @time:1s)
{
  @stop-1:~"@{color}_SOPRA";
  @stop-2:~"@{color}_SOTTO";

  @name: ~"blink-@{color}";
  animation:@name @time ease-in-out infinite alternate;

  .steps()
  {
      0% { color:@@stop-1; }
     50% { color:@@stop-2; }
    100% { color:@@stop-1; }
  }

  @keyframes @name { .steps(); }
}


.zoom_animation (@ratio, @time:1s)
{  
  @zoom-ratio:round(@ratio*100);
  @name: ~"zoom-@{zoom-ratio}";

  animation:@name @time ease-in-out infinite alternate;

  .steps()
  {
      0% { .scale(1.0); }
     50% { .scale(@ratio); }
    100% { .scale(1.0); }
  }

  @keyframes @name { .steps(); }
}
```

each one is called by a different CSS class:

```
.blink
{
  .color_animation(red);
}

.animated-zoom
{
  .zoom_animation(1.05);
}
```

I would like to be able to execute one of them or both in the same time, adding one or both css classes to a DOM element, for example:

```
<p class='blink'>Loading...</p>
<p class='animated-zoom'>Highlight</p>
<p class='blink animated-zoom'>Data not Saved!!!</p>
```

But in last case, second animation overrides the first one.

How to combine them in the special case in which both classes are added?

Comment: IFAIK, you can't combine two animations by combining two classes for the same element (one will always override `animation` property of another). You can however combine two animations in the same class: (by breaking `animation` shorthand to its individual properties and using comma separated list of values for each).

Comment: Yes, got the point... I effectively thought something similar. Do you have some suggestion starting from my code?

Comment: I'd use something like `animation-name+:` in each mixin so you can just call both and get the combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **@seven-phases-max**'s suggestion, I elaborated a possible solution, *pipelining* animations in case more than one CSS class is assigned to an element.

Here my original (now slightly modified) code, in which I move common parts in dedicated COMMONS mixins:

```
.color_animation (@color, @time:1s)
{
  @stop-1:~"@{color}_SOPRA";
  @stop-2:~"@{color}_SOTTO";

  @name: ~"blink-@{color}";

  .steps()
  {
      0% { color:@@stop-1; }
    100% { color:@@stop-2; }
  }

  @value:@name @time ease-in-out infinite alternate;

  .INITIALIZE_keyframes();
  .CALL_animation();
}


.zoom_animation (@ratio, @time:1s)
{  
  @zoom-ratio:round(@ratio*100);
  @name: ~"zoom-@{zoom-ratio}";

  .steps()
  {
      0% { .scale(1.0); }
    100% { .scale(@ratio); }
  }

  @value:@name @time ease-in-out infinite alternate;

  .INITIALIZE_keyframes();
  .CALL_animation();
}
```

Here the COMMONS mixins declaration (*I'm missing browsers browsers prefix for simplicity, but they could be added here*):

```
.INITIALIZE_keyframes()
{
  @keyframes @name { .steps(); }
}

.CALL_animation()
{
  animation+:@value;
}
```

Please, note the '**+**' sign in `animation` declaration, it's the [secret](http://lesscss.org/features/#merge-feature-comma) of my solution, coupled with the following CSS classes declaration:

```
.blink
{
  .color_animation(red);
}

.animated-zoom
{
  .zoom_animation(1.05);
}

.blink
{
  &.animated-zoom
  {  
    .color_animation(red);
    .animated-zoom;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer that was posted was great and helped me find my own solution to the problem. I use a generic keyframe and animation mixin to create my animations like this:

```
// Generic keyframe class
.keyframes(@name; @arguments) {
    @-moz-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
    @-webkit-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
  @-ms-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
  @-o-keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
    @keyframes @name { @arguments(); }
}

// Generic animation class
.animation(@arguments) {
    -webkit-animation+: @arguments;
    -moz-animation+: @arguments;
  -ms-animation+: @arguments;
  -o-animation+: @arguments;
    animation+: @arguments;
}
```

Note the `+` in the `.animation` class. Then I can build animations quickly like so:

```
// Fade in animation
.fadeIn() {
  .keyframes(fade-in; {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
  });

  .animation(fade-in 1.5s);
}

// Pan animation
.pan() {
  .keyframes(pan; {
    from { transform: translateX(-2%); }
    to { transform: translateX(2%); }
  });

  .animation(pan 5s infinite alternate ease-in-out);
}
```

Now if I want to use animations together, I can simply add them to an existing class, element, etc.:

```
.multipleAnimations {
   .fadeIn();
   .pan();
}
```

Comment: Great. Just one suggestion: stop using mixins for cross-compatiblity, use a plugin for this purpose instead. Often many cross-compatibility fallback are quite old and maybe not necessary